# Why is the click event not firing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, absolute

I have a button inside of an absolute position div; It has a click handler but it's not firing. I also have a `mousedown` event on the absolute positioned div. When I remove the `mousedown` handler from the parent div, the `click` handler will work correctly.

Here is the markup and CSS:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="selection">
        <button class="close-button">✖</button>
    </div>
</div>

.selection {
    position: absolute;
    top: 303px;
    left: 92.5px;
    height: 440px;
    width: 50vw;
    background-color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.close-button {
    height: 22px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18pt;
    line-height: 20px;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The button is rendered on top of the absolute div

[image]

Why are these events conflicting and how can I fix this?

-- EDIT --

I have confirmed that the event handlers actually do exist on the DOM as I expect them to. I can fire them manually from the console. I did not include the event handlers in my example as it was written in React.

Comment: Can you post the event handler wire-up?

Comment: @SuperJumbo I can confirm the events are wired correctly. This work was done in React.js and I'm afraid it would complicate the question.

Comment: I want to say that the `mousedown` handler on the div is going to shadow the `click` handler – `click` requires that you also `mouseup` whereas `mousedown` is fired before because it doesn't have that requirement

Comment: @SuperJumbo This issue also occurs when I use `mouseup` instead of `click` on the button

Comment: Does it work when you reverse the handlers? Put the `click` on the div and the `mousedown` on the button?

Comment: @SuperJumbo Yes, but now they are both getting fired. Also, I specifically wanted the `mouseup` event on the button. I wanted the user to be able to mousedown on the div (to move it up and down), and then pan over the x and let go of click to delete the div.

Comment: I get that you don't want to post your code if it complicates things, but at the very least create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Most people can't be bothered writing their own testing code just to verify your problem and try to find a solution for it. If you want people to spend their time to help you out with nothing in return, you should at the very least make it as easy as possible for them to do so :)

Comment: @icecub I will create an MCVE and update this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that **mousedown** differs from the **click** event which is fired after a full click action occurs; that is, the mouse button is pressed and released while the pointer remains inside the same element. mousedown is fired the moment the button is initially pressed.

What the **mousedown even**t is doing ? the mousedown event handler must have done a work that prevents the **click** from working.

Comment: You are correct. When I remove the logic from `mousedown` listener, the issue no longer occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try with this code Hope It's Work

`Html` code is like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main_section">
        <div class="selection"></div> 
        <button class="close-button">✖</button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

You can use this `css`

```
<style>
.main_section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 303px;
    left: 92.5px;
    height: 440px;
    width: 50vw;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.selection{ 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index:1;
    position: absolute;
}
.close-button {
    height: 22px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18pt;
    line-height: 20px;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index:2;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

and add this click event

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".close-button").click(function(){
    alert("Hello");
  });
  $( ".selection" ).mousedown(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .mousedown() called." );
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function MyClick(){
alert("Close button clicked");
}
```

```css
.selection {
    position: absolute;
    top: 303px;
    left: 92.5px;
    height: 440px;
    width: 50vw;
    background-color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.close-button {
    height: 22px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18pt;
    line-height: 20px;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="selection">
        <button class="close-button" onClick="MyClick()">✖</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry if i am wrong. but as per my understanding on click close button it not fire that is your problem right? so check below code that work fine on click close button.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I did not include the event listener mounting in my code as it was written in React. Please assume the event handlers are correctly mounted (I have verified this).